# toString() in Typescript

Tags: typescript, type-conversion

I think that TypeScript compiler should realize when a Type could be seen as Unit and use it as Unit, but when I try the following [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Documents%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20title%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.title%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Unit%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%3D%20'My%20Name'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20documents%3A%20Documents%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(name%3Astring%2C%20documents%3ADocuments%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.name%20%3D%20name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.documents%20%3D%20documents%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20toString()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.name%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20req%20%3D%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Unit%201'%2C%20documents%3A%20%5B%7B%20title%3A%20null%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20title%3A%20'I%20have%20title'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20title%3A%20null%20%7D%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20cast%3CT%3E(param%3A%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20result%3A%20T%20%3D%20param%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log('Unit%3A%20'%2C%20cast%3CUnit%3E(req).toString())%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log('docs%3A%20'%2C%20cast%3CUnit%3E(req).documents%5B0%5D.toString())%0D%0Aconsole.log('Now%20using%20unit%20as%20directly')%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log((req%20as%20Unit).toString())%0D%0Aconsole.log((%3CUnit%3Ereq).toString())%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log('Converting%20to%20Unit%20manually')%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20Unit(req.name%2C%20req.documents).toString())%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(new%20Unit(req.name%2C%20req.documents).documents%5B0%5D.toString())%3B) it shows me that key words as **as**, operators like **< ClassName >** doesn't work as expected or am I missing something? From my point of view TypeScript is only guarantee types when those functions/constructors are used explicitly:

**TypeScript code:**

```
class Documents{
    title: string;

    toString() {
        return this.title;
    }
}
class Unit {

    name: string = 'My Name';
    documents: Documents[];

    constructor(name:string, documents:Documents[]) {
        this.name = name;
        this.documents = documents;
    }

    toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}

let req = { name: 'Unit 1', documents: [{ title: null }, { title: 'I have title' }, { title: null }] };

function cast<T>(param: T) {
    let result: T = param;
    return result;
}

console.log('Unit: ', cast<Unit>(req).toString());
console.log('docs: ', cast<Unit>(req).documents[0].toString())
console.log('Now using unit as directly');
console.log((req as Unit).toString())
console.log((<Unit>req).toString())

console.log('Converting to Unit manually')
console.log(new Unit(req.name, req.documents).toString());
console.log(new Unit(req.name, req.documents).documents[0].toString());
```

**And the console result is the following:**

```
Unit:  [object Object]
(unknown) docs:  [object Object]
(unknown) Now using unit as directly
(unknown) [object Object]
(unknown) [object Object]
(unknown) Converting to Unit manually
(unknown) Unit 1
(unknown) [object Object]
```

**Expected behavior:**

```
Unit:  Unit 1
(unknown) docs:  title1
(unknown) Now using unit as directly
(unknown) Unit 1
(unknown) Unit 1
(unknown) Converting to Unit manually
(unknown) Unit 1
(unknown) title 1
```

Comment: The types in TypeScript are more like with JSDoc. You can declare a wrong type with `as` or `<MyType>` but it will have no effect at runtime.

Comment: @Paleo This can be fixed in runtime. I can fix it in a general way using a function for transform any type to any other using the rules that they use. Which the main is ( let leftPart:AType = rightPart ) : if all the properties of the left part are in the right part I can make the assignment. From my point of view, they are only missing assign the code of functions. It's like they only assign properties and not functions. Which leads a this type of behavior.

Comment: Yes, a type can be changed at runtime but you have to write the code to do this. TypeScript will not help you. Look at your code in the Playground (the link you posted here). In the right side, the function `cast` do nothing. You have to implement it yourself.

Comment: @Paleo that's definitely the question, is supposed to work like that? Because a general workaround can be made easily. It can be inferred in runtime always ( at least using the operators ). Because they are statictyped operators

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to work that way. Notice: I think that `as` and `<MyType>` are not operators. If you want a function that makes an instance of `Unit` from JSON data, you need to implement it yourself with `new Unit()` etc.

Comment: @Paleo as is a keyword and <>, I think is an operator. In any case, I tried to search for the Typescript specification Language which I only find this one: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification%20(Change%20Markup).pdf
That was updated in Jan 2016 and has a lot of strikeouts. That's why I'm not sure that is supposed to work like that or is something in process. Etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154237/discussion-between-titusfx-and-paleo).